# Get code to reject username if it exists in the ArrayList.

Tags: java, client, chatroom

In a Chatroom code, I have been trying to figure out how to add a code so I can reject client with a username that already exists. I have created an `ArrayList` where I can store the usernames of the connected clients. But every time I run a client, it accepts a name that I have previously used. This is my code.

```
if(obj == login) {
  // Need to establish a connection request
  String username = tf.getText().trim();
  clientList.add(username);
  // ignore empty username

  if(username.length() == 0 || username.equals("Your name")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a valid username","Alert Message",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;
  }

  if(clientList.size() > 1 && clientList.contains(username)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This username is in use","Alert Message",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;
  }

  // try creating a new Client with GUI
  client = new Client(username, this);
  // test if we can start the Client

  if(!client.start()) 
    return;

  //clientList.add(client);
  tf.setText("");
  tf.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  label.setText("Enter your message in the yellow box");
  connected = true;
  login.setEnabled(false);
  logout.setEnabled(true);
  tf.addActionListener(this);
  // Action listener for when the user enter a message
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: You probably shouldn't add the username to the `clientList` until you've verified they aren't already in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment of @Elliott-Frisch, You need to add `username` to clientList after you check its validity. You may also simplify `clientList.size() > 1 && clientList.contains(username))` as `clientList.contains(username)`

You can just put `clientList.add(username);` before the line you create the client object:

```
clientList.add(username);
//try creating a new Client with GUI
client = new Client(username, this);
//test if we can start the Client
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!clientList.contains(username)){

  clientList.add(username);

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("What does your code mean and how does it solve the problem?")`

Comment: it means that if ArrayList of usernames already contains specified username it'll tell you. The "!" means that you want the code inside if statement to execute if it doesn't contain one. How does it solve the problem? Well: "(...) so I can reject client with a username that already exists (...)" <-- that's how.

Comment: That's all true, but he already checks if the list contains the user. The problem is as stated by Elliott: he adds the user before verifying. For future reference: don't just paste code in an answer. Provide the explanation you've given in the comments as well and you would have a lot better answer (if it would have been the actual issue).

Comment: Yes and I just did the edit. If you put my code around the clientList.add(username); call in the question it does exactly what Elliot says, so how am I wrong here?